# A combination of a list given a length followed by a permutation in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, combinations, permutation

I need a predicate to return a list with all combinations of the input list, and the list result size is in the second param, the predicate would be like this

```
permutInListN( +inputList, +lengthListResult, -ListResult),
```

example:

```
permutInListN([1,2,3],2,L).
? L=[1,2].
? L=[2,1].
? L=[1,3].
? L=[3,1].
? L=[2,3].
? L=[3,2].
```

Combinations of `[1,2,3]` in a list `L` with length `2`.
with no repetitions maybe using setoff.

this is my code but it doesn't work at all , no generate all solutions

```
permutInListN(_, 0, []).
permutInListN([X|Xs], N, [X|Ys]) :- N1 is N-1, permutInListN(Xs,N1,Ys).
permutInListN([_|Xs], N, Y) :- N>0, permutInListN(Xs,N,Y).

?permutInListN([1,2,3],2,L).
L = [1, 2]
L = [1, 3]
L = [2, 3]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: My bad, removed the flag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is a combination followed by a permutation.

For combination:

```
comb(0,_,[]).

comb(N,[X|T],[X|Comb]) :-
    N>0,
    N1 is N-1,
    comb(N1,T,Comb).

comb(N,[_|T],Comb) :-
    N>0,
    comb(N,T,Comb).
```

Example:

```
?- comb(2,[1,2,3],List).
List = [1, 2] ;
List = [1, 3] ;
List = [2, 3] ;
false.
```

For Permutation just use SWI-Prolog `permutation/2` in library lists

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).

?- permutation([1,2],R).
R = [1, 2] ;
R = [2, 1] ;
false.
```

Putting them together

```
comb_perm(N,List,Result) :-
    comb(N,List,Comb),
    permutation(Comb,Result).
```

With your query

```
?- comb_perm(2,[1,2,3],R).
R = [1, 2] ;
R = [2, 1] ;
R = [1, 3] ;
R = [3, 1] ;
R = [2, 3] ;
R = [3, 2] ;
false.
```

Modified for your predicate

```
permutInListN(List,N,Result) :-
    comb(N,List,Comb),
    permutation(Comb,Result).
```

Example

```
?- permutInListN([1,2,3],2,R).
R = [1, 2] ;
R = [2, 1] ;
R = [1, 3] ;
R = [3, 1] ;
R = [2, 3] ;
R = [3, 2] ;
false.
```

Comment: The `permutation/2` predicate in SWI-Prolog is a *library* predicate, not a *built-in* predicate.

Comment: @PauloMoura Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Permutating the result

Your `permutInListN/3` predicate basically takes `N` elements in an *ordered* way from the given list, but the order of the elements that are picked, is the same as the original order.

We can thus post-process this list, by finding all permutations of the selected elements, so something like:

```
permutInListN(L, N, R) :-
    takeN(L, N, S),
    permutation(S, R).
```

with `takeN/3` almost equivalent to the predicate you defined:

```
takeN(_, 0, []).
takeN([X|Xs], N, [X|Ys]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    takeN(Xs,N1,Ys).
takeN([_|Xs], N, Y) :-
    N > 0,
    takeN(Xs,N,Y).
```

[**`permutation/3`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=permutation/2) is a predicate from the [`lists` library [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists).

## Using *N* `select/3`s

We can also solve the problem by `N` times using the [**`select/3`** predicate [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3). `select(X, L, R)` takes an element `X` from a list, and `R` is a list, without that element. We can thus recursively pass the list and each time remove an element, until we removed `N` elements, like:

```
permutInListN(_, 0, []).
permutInListN(L, N, [X|T]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    select(X, L, R),
    permutInListN(R, N1, T).
```