# (prolog) Can i abstract all the permutations of this pattern instead of having to write each one individually?

Tags: prolog

I'm just starting out with prolog and though I think I'm getting a pretty good handle on how to use it, I've hit a wall here. I have a rule like this:

```
foo(A, B, C) :- bar(A, B), baz(C).
foo(A, B, C) :- bar(A, C), baz(B).
foo(A, B, C) :- bar(B, A), baz(C).
% etc, etc, for all permutations of `A, B, C`
```

However, the real rule has more than 3 parameters and writing them all out/generating them all would make me end up with a very, very large file. Is there a way to abstract this pattern?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do:

```
foo(A, B, C) :- 
    select(X, [A, B, C], L1),
    select(Y, L1, [Z]),
    bar(X, Y),
    baz(Z).
```

The idea being that we'll get each combination of these parameters reshuffled using [`select/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3) (one of my favorite predicates) and then having permuted them we can just hand off to the two predicates you care about.

It might be more clear to do this, but L2 is always going to contain a single element, so I just matched it out in the previous clause above:

```
foo(A, B, C) :- 
    select(X, [A, B, C], L1),
    select(Y, L1, L2),
    select(Z, L2, _),
    bar(X, Y),
    baz(Z).
```

**Edit**: Let's handle arbitrary N. First we'll need a `select_n/4` which gives me N items from the list. I'm going to write this with a DCG because it's easier for me:

```
select_n([X|Xs], N) --> select(X), { succ(N0, N) }, select_n(Xs, N0).
select_n([], 0) --> [].
```

DCGs are not just a great way to parse text, they're also a handy way for string together predicates that have an input list and output list.

Now we can use this helper to build a more general version of your predicate. Let's say you take a list for simplicity:

```
foo(L) :-
    select_n(BarArgs, 2, L, L1),
    select_n(BazArgs, 1, L1, []),
    apply(bar, BarArgs), 
    apply(baz, BazArgs).
```

You could replace the `2` and `1` above with whatever you want, presumably based on the arity of `bar` and `baz` that you're wanting to call.

If you're not using SWI, or you just want to use `call/1` instead, you would have to use the univ operator `=..` to build the term before using `call/1`:

```
foo(L) :-
    select_n(BarArgs, 2, L, L1),
    select_n(BazArgs, 1, L1, []),
    Bar =.. [bar|BarArgs],
    Baz =.. [baz|BazArgs],
    call(Bar),
    call(Baz).
```

Comment: While I haven't tried it, would not `=..` be more useful. Then the code is not dependent upon an exact number of arguments.

Comment: @GuyCoder I've edited the answer, please let me know what you think.

Comment: I see why it didn't work for me for arrays other than length of 3. I was thinking that they were independent of size, but I see that they are hard coded with `1` and `2`.

Comment: I was thinking it would work like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53669268/1243762)

Comment: @GuyCoder if that's what he wants, that answer is good, but I think he always has N arguments spread across M predicates, each with their own arity, but which adds up to N. At least, that was what I inferred from the question. Of course, I wasn't planning on trying to answer the implied question when the direct question was straightforward. It's usually better to just answer the direct question. But you made me do it. :)

Comment: I didn't make you do, you know it was just a challenge you wanted to do. :) I would have answered this question but I don't think that the answers he gets here are the answer to his problem in the long term. This seems like a problem where you have to remember that data is code and code is data and he hard coded something in the arguments that should not be hard coded. Your answer was close when you changed the arguments from a set number to a list.

Comment: @GuyCoder I think the real problem is the combinatorial explosion he's going to experience when N exceeds fairly small numbers, but knowing how to mess around with Prolog's evaluation is a key to using it productively I think.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is very good already. Just some further thoughts.

In Prolog it is very easy to write mini-interpreters for your micro-languages. Here is yet another (cheap) way to solve your original problem:

```
foo(A, B, C) :-
    permutation([A, B, C], [X, Y, Z]),
    bar(X, Y), baz(Z).
```

... and with `call`, you can parametrize `bar` and `baz`:

```
foo(Bar, Baz, A, B, C) :-
    permutation([A, B, C], [X, Y, Z]),
    call(Bar, X, Y), call(Baz, Z).
```

This means that you can now pass (by name) any predicate with arity 2 as `Bar` and any predicate with arity 1 as `Baz`. And if you have a predicate `bar_x` that takes 3 arguments, you can bind the first one early. For example, you could call your `foo/5` as:

```
?- foo(bar(hello), baz, 1, 2, 3).
```

this will evaluate `bar(hello, 1, 2)` for the first solution.

So now the only non-trivial question is, what is your interface? How do you want to write down your queries? Do you provide the three arguments as separate arguments or as a list? Do you want to parametrize the predicates called? And so on.